# How to make a page invisible for a period of time using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making an ajax call to a server as soon as i enter a page... Now i want to make the page invisible or hidden until the ajax request is made properly... How to do that?

Comment: I suggest you show a "loading" thingy. I hate blank screens that does not inform me that things are actually happening

Comment: @mplungjan i also wanted that. But i am facing an issue in that.. Actually When i come to page then i am plotting 4 pie charts... I am plotting all the 4 but later hiding the rest three... So if i show progress bar then i am able to see all the pie charts being plotted and then hidden... Do u have any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
$("*").hide();
```

Later, when your AJAX call has completed, you can do

```
$("*").show();
```

Comment: I am getting this error  : E/Web Console(389): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: body at file:///android_asset/www/index.html?start:700

Comment: Hmm. You'll want to put `$("*").show();` in the return function for your AJAX call. Are you doing that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9764/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-elliot-bonneville)